# Ext.js Tool bar

Tags: extjs

I am new to ext.js. I have been learning from Sencha Documentation. I am trying to implement tool bars in a panel. I am using 'tbar'. I was wondering if I can create a stack of tool bars on top of a panel. e.g. I want 3 tool bars on top; one after other.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance for the guidance.

Comment: Please post some code to show us what you have tried already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming from 4.2.2 Documentation http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-tbar

```
tbar : Object/Object[]
```

Convenience config. Short for 'Top Bar'.

```
tbar: [
  { xtype: 'button', text: 'Button 1' }
]
```

is equivalent to

```
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'top',
    items: [
        { xtype: 'button', text: 'Button 1' }
    ]
}]
```

You can add multiple toolbars by using the bottom configuration like so, though I'm not sure it will look how you are thinking.

```
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'top',
    items: [
        { xtype: 'button', text: 'Button 1' }
    ]
},{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'top',
    items: [
        { xtype: 'button', text: 'Button 2' }
    ]
}]
```

---

An example as part of a panel

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    width: '100%',
    //tbar: [
        //{ xtype: 'displayfield', fieldLabel: ' tool bar 1' }
    //]

    //Instead of tbar(above) use the full dockedItems config
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'top',
        items: [
            { xtype: 'displayfield', fieldLabel: ' tool bar 1' }
        ]
    },{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'top',
        items: [
            { xtype: 'displayfield', fieldLabel: ' tool bar 2' }
        ]
    }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
})
```

Comment: Note that this may or may not be similar for other versions of ExtJS. The version in this example is 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the guidance. I implemented 'tbar' as following. Is it a correct approach?

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    layout: 'vbox',
    width: '100%',
    defaults: {
        frame: true,
    },

   items: [
         {
             xtype: 'panel',
             width: '100%',
             border: false, frame: false,
             tbar: [
                     { xtype: 'displayfield', fieldLabel: ' tool bar 1' }
             ]
         },
     {
         xtype: 'panel',
         width: '100%',
         border: false, frame: false,
         tbar: [
              { xtype: 'displayfield', fieldLabel: ' tool bar 2' },
         ]
     },
       {
           xtype: 'panel',
           width: '100%',
           border: false, frame: false,
           tbar: [
                { xtype: 'displayfield', fieldLabel: ' tool bar 3' },
           ]
       }
    ],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
 })
```

Comment: That looks like it would work, though the extra panels may be unnecessary. I will give edit my answer to better illustrate what I meant though.